# Symbolicate Flutter crash

Tags: flutter, debug-symbols

While running my app in Android Studio, it crashes with:

```
F/libc    (28855): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 28898 (1.ui), pid 28855 (nalquest.survey)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'motorola/guamna_retail/guamna:11/RZA31.Q2-146-14-22-2/8a7d1:user/release-keys'
Revision: 'pvt'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2023-09-15 11:29:06-0400
pid: 28855, tid: 28898, name: 1.ui  >>> com.signalquest.survey <<<
uid: 10497
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
Cause: null pointer dereference
    x0  0000006e0069b9e1  x1  0000000000000000  x2  0000000000000000  x3  0000000000000000
    x4  0000000000000000  x5  0000006e0920cfd1  x6  0000006e0a3d4430  x7  000000000000534f
    x8  0000000000000007  x9  0000000000000001  x10 000000700cbf4c68  x11 0000000000000001
    x12 000000000003c000  x13 0000000000000010  x14 0000006e09980081  x15 0000007009c09ae8
    x16 0000007009b31000  x17 0000006e08f00e01  x18 000000700980a000  x19 0000007009b30000
    x20 0000006e08052be1  x21 b4000071d3115f70  x22 0000006e00008081  x23 b4000071d3115f70
    x24 0000006e08456f51  x25 0000007009b30000  x26 b4000071d3115f70  x27 0000006e08456f20
    x28 000000080000006e  x29 0000007009c09af8
    lr  0000007012308184  sp  0000007009b30000  pc  0000006fe493497c  pst 0000000020000000
backtrace:
      #00 pc 000000000003497c  [anon:dart-code]
```

I'm also able to reproduce this when debugging the Android project in Android Studio, but I get an opaque stack trace, there, too.

Here are details of my Flutter environment:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.2, on macOS 13.4.1 22F770820d darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.13.2 on channel stable at /Users/csabbey/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/3.3.6/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision ff5b5b5fa6 (3 weeks ago), 2023-08-24 08:12:28 -0500
    • Engine revision b20183e040
    • Dart version 3.1.0
    • DevTools version 2.25.0
```

I came across `flutter symbolize`, but to use that, it looks like I'd have to run an obfuscated version of my project, where I generate the debug info for it to use, but I would imagine the unobfuscated version would be symbolicatable.

How can I find the cause of this 'null pointer dereference'?

Edit @DharamBudh asked for my pubspec file; here are my direct dependencies:

- build_runner 2.4.5
- collection 1.17.2
- community_charts_flutter 1.0.1
- connectivity_plus 4.0.1
- convert 3.1.1
- csv 5.0.2
- drift 2.9.0
- drift_db_viewer 2.0.0
- drift_dev 2.9.0
- dxf 3.1.1
- ffi 2.0.2
- ffigen 8.0.2
- file_picker 5.2.10
- firebase_auth 4.6.3
- firebase_core 2.14.0
- firebase_core_web 2.6.0
- firebase_crashlytics 3.3.3
- flutter 0.0.0
- flutter_blue_plus 1.14.16
- flutter_colorpicker 1.0.3
- flutter_compass 0.7.0
- flutter_keyboard_visibility_web 2.0.0
- flutter_launcher_icons 0.13.1
- flutter_lints 2.0.1
- flutter_midi 1.1.0
- flutter_native_splash 2.3.1
- flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle 2.0.15
- flutter_secure_storage 8.0.0
- flutter_secure_storage_web 1.1.1
- flutter_signin_button 2.0.0
- flutter_test 0.0.0
- flutter_typeahead 4.6.2
- flutter_web_plugins 0.0.0
- geolocator 9.0.2
- geolocator_web 2.1.6
- get_it 7.6.0
- google_sign_in 6.1.4
- http 0.13.6
- http_parser 4.0.2
- integration_test 0.0.0
- intl 0.18.1
- logger 1.4.0
- maplibre_gl 0.16.0
- mockito 5.4.2
- numberpicker 2.1.2
- package_info_plus 3.1.2
- path 1.8.3
- path_provider 2.0.15
- patrol 2.0.2
- permission_handler 10.4.3
- screen_brightness 0.2.2
- share_plus 6.3.4
- sqlite3_flutter_libs 0.5.15
- synchronized 3.1.0
- uuid 3.0.7
- wakelock 0.6.2

Comment: I tried addr2line and ndk-stack, from https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Crashes#symbolicating-stack-traces-for-engine-crashes, but these addresses aren't found.

Comment: It is a memory allocation / de-allocation problem. Flutter try catch won't work here. I solved it yesterday. One of my flutter packages was responsible for the issue. So, could you provide your pubspec file?

Comment: You can use `adb logcat` to get a better understanding of what's happening. https://developer.android.com/tools/logcat

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your issue is with package "maplibre_gl", you can check this issue on github: https://github.com/maplibre/flutter-maplibre-gl/issues/182

And see the commit made: https://github.com/maplibre/flutter-maplibre-gl/pull/259.
Since is merged into main branch you can install package from main branch and try the fix in your project.

like this:

```
dependencies:
    ...
    maplibre_gl:
      git:
        url: https://github.com/maplibre/flutter-maplibre-gl.git
        ref: main
```

I hope you solve the problem.
best regards